# Can't change payment method in CiviProfile

Tags: civicontribute, payment, payment-method

We have Civi 5.8.1 on WordPress 5.1

A new contribution was added by an Admin.  Check was accidentally selected and saved for the Payment Method.  When we tried to edit that and change it to the correct Payment Method it just spins after clicking update and nothing happens.  Is this a bug that will be fixed in an update?  Does anyone else have this problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try a right-click to open in a new page as you are more likely to see errors reported

Comment: You are right. I added a 4th image to show the error I get there.  Mandatory Key missing from total amount.

Comment: so it doesn't like a $0 amount. not surprising. why do you need any record for a $0 ?